# loading quicklisp in a program

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

What's the correct way to load quicklisp at the start of my program? I'm currently copy/pasting in the block that quicklisp inserted into my .eclrc, e.g.

```lisp
;;; quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))

(ql:quickload "iterate")
```

but it seems like there has to be a less messy way to do things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't really a good way to do that. It's more part of the development environment than the deployment environment.

I use buildapp to deploy CL programs, and there's a way for Quicklisp to export its index of systems and buildapp to load it.

There's certainly room for improvement.