# How do I load a library before I build an executable with BUILDAPP. on Ubuntu using SBCL

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, common-lisp, executable, cffi

I'm trying to use buildapp to load cffi before I run (cffi:null-pointer) as a test function to make sure I can build cffi executables.

cffi is located `/home/w/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2` on my box.
Here is how I'am attempting to do it, per the buildapp doc. [here](http://www.xach.com/lisp/buildapp/#example)

but I'm getting this error: `Component "cffi" not found1`

Here is one of many attempts:

```
    buildapp --output cffi --asdf-path ~/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/ \
        --load-system cffi\
        --eval '(defun main (args) (write-string (null-pointer)))' \
        --entry main
```

Any help on how to do this is appreciated.  I'm un Ubuntu Trusty, using SBCL, QUICKLISP,  running this in the terminal from the /home/w/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2 directory,

Comment: I got a similliar question/problem - might be worth taking a look at some of the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917067/how-to-use-buildapp-in-combination-with-quicklisp