# How to fix asdf error when using buildapp on a quicklisp project

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf

I've been making my first quicklisp project lately and I wanted to share it. I've put [it](https://github.com/Trashtalk217/ltk-colorpicker) on github, but not everyone has emacs + slime + quicklisp installed so I wanted to make an executable I could put with the code.

To do this I'm using `buildapp` and following the steps laid out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917067/how-to-use-buildapp-in-combination-with-quicklisp) stackoverflow answer.

```
$ sbcl --no-userinit --no-sysinit --non-interactive \
       --load ~/quicklisp/setup.lisp \
       --eval '(ql:quickload "ltk-colorpicker")' \
       --eval '(ql:write-asdf-manifest-file "quicklisp-manifest.txt")'

$ buildapp --output out \
           --manifest-file quicklisp-manifest.txt \
           --load-system ltk-colorpicker \
           --entry colorpicker
```

After running those commands I get the following error:

```
Fatal INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD:
  READ error during LOAD:

    The symbol "*SYSTEM-DEFINITION-SEARCH-FUNCTIONS*" is not external in the ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM package.

      Line: 16, Column: 90, File-Position: 15267

      Stream: #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file /home/nathan/quicklisp/local-projects/ltk-colorpicker/dumper-2SKVI5f7.lisp" {1001B70F83}>
```

The main problem here is that I don't even have a clue at how to begin to fix it. I've seen [this](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/714) gibhub issue, but that had to do with problems with Homebrew and it never even mentions `buildapp`. It's all very confusing. And I hope I could get some help.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: The github issue you mention _does_ mention buildapp, and it seems to me that the problem lies in a missing backwards compatibility between ASDF and buildapp.  Maybe you need a newer version of buildapp (or build that from source).

Comment: FYI, you don't *have* to use buildapp to build executables. We can use `asdf:make`, see https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/scripting.html#with-asdf and ps: I demand a screenshot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce the error. As suggested in the comments, you can build an up-to-date version of `buildapp` as follows:

```
$ sbcl
* (ql:quickload :buildapp)
...

* (buildapp:build-buildapp 
    (merge-pathnames "bin/buildapp" (user-homedir-pathname)))
```

This build `$HOME/bin/buildapp`. When I use the new binary, there is no error anymore.

You can also avoid generating an executable (that can end up being outdated) by systematically calling the `buildapp::main` function from Common Lisp; you will then always have the version that corresponds to the current release of quicklisp:

```
* (buildapp::main 
    '("BUILDAPP" ;; argv[0] must exist but the value is not important
      "--manifest-file" "/tmp/quicklisp-manifest.txt" 
      "--load-system" "drakma" "--output" "/tmp/test"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Some extra info from my point:

The solution was to use the newest version of `buildapp` as @coredump mentioned. I updated by going to the [github page](https://github.com/xach/buildapp), downloading the zip and doing the following commands at the point where `buildapp` is stored.

```
$ make
$ cp buildapp /usr/bin
```

(This of course only works on linux.)
This is not an elegant solution but `buildapp` hasn't updated in 4 years, I think it's a safe enough bet. I also made a mistake with the command. The `--entry` part is wrong. It should have been: `--entry ltk-colorpicker::main`` where main is a function that takes one variable since that's required by the [spec](https://www.xach.com/lisp/buildapp/).

Main is just this: `(main (i) (declare (ignore i)) (colorpicker))`